unable to change desktop icon in KDE
In KDE some icons on my desktop have no icon, and there appears to be no way to change them. One example is Waterfox:

I have tried right-clicking > Properties on the icon as you can see in the screenshot above, and here in Dolphin by right-clicking the icon and selecting "Configure":

Is there any way to change these icons?

This question is similar to: Creating a .desktop file for a new application. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Create a .desktop file, and use an appropriate icon for it.

Change the icons no. It is how it was made but you could do what @Archisman Panigrahi suggested. This will give you an icon on your desktop with the icon you want but will not change the one on the apps list.

@David If the desktop file is placed in .local/share/applications, then the correct icon will be shown in the apps list. I am assuming that waterfox is just a binary executable that does not show up in the apps list.
